# TYPO3: How to restrict the file upload in Powermail with the file formats

Tags: file-upload, typo3, typo3-10.x, powermail

I am using powermail where I have added a file upload which I want to restrict with PNG,JPG and PDF file formats. Since I unfortunately do not work as long as TYPO3 and the extension Powermail I do not know exactly where I have to make the changes.
I have already seen in another forum post that you can make the adjustments in the setup.

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite{
   upload.file_extensions = jpg,png,pdf
}
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the allowed fileextension as TypoScript constant [`plugin.tx_powermail.misc.uploadFileExtensions`](https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/eb56868920f3ed38c4198d7825501bc2dc07a8c3/Configuration/TypoScript/Main/constants.typoscript#L218).

So, the TypoScript (in constant section) should look like:

```
plugin.tx_powermail.misc {
   uploadFileExtensions = jpg,png,pdf
}
```

`file_extensions` seems to be a configuration value years ago (The mentioned post was from 2011), but does not exist in the current powermail code.

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to know that in Powermail 9.0.2 this configuration doesn't work. This is how to acheive the same result in Powermail 9

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.misc.file.extension = jpg,png,pdf
```